# Grails + Hibernate-Spatial + Postgis : conflict

Tags: hibernate, grails, postgis, hibernate-spatial

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to set up a project using Grails 2.4.3 and a PostGIS database through the hibernate-spatial-postgresql plugin. It's a sample project, no other plugin than the default ones are installed. I enabled Postgres first, tried to save domains to my database : everything worked fine. But as soon as I enable hibernate-spatial it's not working anymore.

I'm having the exact same issue as [this person does](http://thespatialperspective.wordpress.com/2013/10/02/grails-hibernate-spatial-and-postgis/).

I tried excluding "hibernate-core:3.6.0.Final" as he does, but I keep getting the same error. Probably because he uses it with Grails 2.3.0 and I'm using 2.4.3.

I removed the dependency "hibernate-spatial-postgresql" under the plugin part of the BuildConfig.groovy file, still getting the same error.

I really don't know what I should look for. It's for sure a conflict between two libraries, or two versions of hibernate/hibernate-spatial.

I'd like to know if anyone here managed to have Grails and a spatial database playing nicely together ? If so, which database did you use ? How did you configure it ?

EDIT : I already tried replacing the Hibernate4 dependency under the "plugins" section of `BuildConfig.groovy` with the Hibernate 3 one (which is commented in the file generated by Grails), then excluding `'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:3.6.0.Final'`. Excluding `'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:3.6.10.17'` doesn't work either.

Thanks a lot for any answer you could give.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using 2.4.x you likely have a dependency on the hibernate4 plugin, not the hibernate (v3) plugin. But the older plugin is there commented out, so remove the line for hibernate4 and uncomment the other (e.g. `runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.17"`). You'll also need to update the `cache.region.factory_class` setting in DataSource.groovy

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I should have mentioned I already tried replacing the hibernate4 dependency with hibernate3 and it didn't work either. I'll try updating the `cache.region.factory_class` though. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I forgot about the `cache.region.factory_class` indeed.